# Flask-SQLAlchemy: declarative model with generated attributes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a class representing a report and containing a pretty long list of checks and associated comments that looks something like this:

```
class Report(db.Model):
  check_1 = db.Column(db.Boolean, info={'label': 'Check 1'})
  check_1_comment = db.Column(db.String, info={'label': 'Check 1 comment'})

  check_2 = db.Column(db.Boolean, info={'label': 'Check 2'})
  check_2_comment = db.Column(db.String, info={'label': 'Check 2 comment'})
```

As the attribute setup is significantly more complex than that and the fields regularly change, I'd like to refactor it to generate the attributes from a structure like an OrderedDict.

I tried something using a custom Metaclass, but it seems difficult to do properly given Flask-SQLAlchemy's object hierarchy:

```
class ReportMeta(_BoundDeclarativeMeta):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    klass = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    checks = cls.Meta.checks
    for (key, label) in checks.items():
      setattr(klass, key, db.Column(db.Boolean, info={'label': label}))
      setattr(klass, f'{key_comment}', db.Column(db.Str, info={'label': label}))

class Report(db.Model, metaclass=ReportMeta):
  class Meta:
    checks = OrderedDict([('check_1', 'Check 1'), ('check_2', 'Check 2')])
```

This of course doesn't work because of the conflicting metaclasses between db.Model and ReportMeta.
Is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your ordered dict would contain?

Comment: It's in the second example, within the Meta class of the Report class: `checks = OrderedDict([('check_1', 'Check 1'), ('check_2', 'Check 2')])`